# Get json format from sqlalchemy class

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy

I have written a small tool to generate a json file from sqlalchemy models files to automate the tedious procedure of writing all the sql raws in a json format. The script works, but there are few parts, see get_modules function, that can be improved. I would be glad to have a review of this code. Thanks

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import glob

PATH = sys.argv[1]
output_filename = 'en.json'

intro = ("""
{
  "sidebar": {
      "overview": "Overview",
  }, 
  "about": {
      "title": "title"
    },
    "welcome": {
        "title": "Welcome to the prototype app!"
    },

""")

def get_fields(input_filename):
    """It returns all fields of a model in a list"""
    fields = []
    endpoint = None
    with open(PATH+input_filename, 'r') as inputfile:
        for line in inputfile:
            if '__plural_name__' in line:
                endpoint = line.split('=')[1].strip().replace("'","")
            if '= Column' in line:
                fields.append(line.split()[0])
    return endpoint, fields

def get_modules():
    """It returns a list of all models"""
    files = []
    cwd = os.getcwd()  
    os.chdir(PATH)
    files = glob.glob("*.py")
    os.chdir(cwd)
    return files

if __name__ == "__main__":

    models = get_modules()
    target = open(output_filename, 'w')
    target.write(intro)
    for m in models:
        if m != '__init__.py':
            end_name, attrs = get_fields(m)
            target.write('  "{}": {{\n'.format(end_name))
            target.write('    "title": "{}",\n'.format(end_name))
            target.write('    "fields": {\n')
            for a in attrs:
                target.write('      "{}": "{}",\n'.format(a,a))
            target.write('    }\n')
            target.write('  },\n')
    target.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take advantage of what is already available. For example, the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html). Instead of putting the string together manually, use `json.dumps`.  Python doesn't have a SQLAlchemy library built-in, but you can get one [on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SQLAlchemy), just `pip install SQLAlchemy`. Using this, you can browse https://stackoverflow.com/q/5022066/5827958 to see some simple ways of converting SQLAlchemy to JSON.

You define `files = []` in `get_modules()`. That's unnecessary. Python does not need you to declare variables before using them. Just save yourself that tiny bit of processing time, and take it out.

You can also make use of `os.path`, a built-in pointer to an OS-specific filesystem path module. In `get_modules()`, you can simplify down to:

```
def get_modules():
    return glob.glob(os.path.join(PATH, "*.py"))
```

Since that now returns an absolute path instead of a relative one, you can now use merely `input_filename` instead of `PATH+input_filename` in `get_fields()`.

I would also define `get_modules` as taking an argument for its path. That way, an importing module can use it for whatever path it wants, but your `if __name__ == '__main__'` block will give it `sys.argv[1]`. Since I just changed your function to using absolute paths, `get_fields()` doesn't need to know about `PATH` at all. On the side, you shouldn't be reading `sys.argv` unless `__name__ == '__main__'` anyway.

The purpose of your file is to convert, but an importing module has no access to the conversion code. I would suggest defining a function for the conversion, and then let the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block call that function with `sys.argv[1]` as an argument.

I'm glad that you use a `with` block in `get_fields()`, but I see you aren't in your main code. This could cause unexpected problems if something unexpected happened. You should open a file without a `with` block only in very rare cases.

Comment: thanks a lot for your review. It is really helpful. I will first try to adjust my code, then look at other examples to convert sqlalchemy into json and see if I can use them for what I need